# Como fazer um programa se reiniciar baseado na entrada do usuário?

Tags: small-basic

Estou fazendo que num programa que pede para o usuário se ele quer continuar usando o programa ou se quer sair. Até agora, eu já consigo fazer que o programa fechar com o usuário digitando "fechar", mas quando tento digitar "reiniciar" não acontece nada, só pula a linha no console.

Como faço que o programa realmente se reinicia, ou fechando e reabrindo rapidamente o programa, ou fazendo ela voltar para a pergunta que pede resposta do usuário?

Em um programa exemplo, fazer ela voltar de novo para a pergunta própria de reiniciar ou fechar, ou em um programa maior, fazer ela voltar para a primeira pergunta que necessita que o usuário digite alguma coisa.

No Small Basic, qual seria a melhor classe e método para o que estou falando?

Aqui está o programa atual que tenho em mãos:

```
TextWindow.WriteLine("Programa para fechar e recomeçar")
TextWindow.WriteLine("")

Sub ReiniciarOuFecharPrograma
inicio:
If resposta = "reiniciar" Then
  Goto inicio
ElseIf resposta = "fechar" Then
    Program.End()
  EndIf
EndSub

inicio = Program.GetArgument(20) 

TextWindow.WriteLine("Escreva 'fechar' para sair.")
TextWindow.WriteLine("Escreva 'reiniciar' para recomeçar o programa.")
TextWindow.WriteLine("")
TextWindow.WriteLine("Você quer fechar/reiniciar?")
TextWindow.WriteLine("")
resposta = TextWindow.Read()
ReiniciarOuFecharPrograma()
```

A classe e método `Program.GetArgument()` não seriam as corretas com o que quero fazer, não é? Elas estão interagindo com a linha 20 `resposta = TextWindow.Read()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu imagino que esteja usando uma linguagem introdutória que ninguém usa, só para aprender, certo? Não seria interessante aprender fazer o código de forma organizada? Ou você quer fazer assim mesmo?

Aprender com a documentação do Small Basic é aprender ter vícios de programação. Vou melhorar o código para parecer mais com um código de qualidade. Por exemplo, não use `Goto`. Não utilize variáveis globais (que podem ser vistas pelas sub-rotinas. Mantenho o código simples e bem indentado. O `Program.GetArgument(20)` não faz o que você pensa.

Eu não conheço bem a linguagem, então posso ter errado em alguma coisa. Por exemplo, não sei se tem variável booleana, então preferi usar um inteiro como *flag* do laço `While`. Fiz este laço que é a forma estruturada de controlar o reinicio de execução.

O `While` funciona como um `If`. Ele vai executar o bloco a seguir se a condição for verdadeira. A diferença está no `EndWhile`. Se fosse um `EndIf` certamente a próxima linha a ser executada seria a linha a seguir. No `EndWhile` ele funciona como se fosse um `Goto`, mas de forma estruturada, ele voltará obrigatoriamente para o `While`. E lá haverá uma nova decisão se deve executar o bloco ou não.

Na prática este código irá encerrar sempre que não for digitado `reiniciar`. Reproduzi o comportamento do código na pergunta, apesar de isto não fazer muito sentido.

```
continua = 1
While continua = 1
    TextWindow.WriteLine("Programa para fechar e recomeçar")
    TextWindow.WriteLine("")
    TextWindow.WriteLine("Escreva 'fechar' para sair.")
    TextWindow.WriteLine("Escreva 'reiniciar' para recomeçar o programa.")
    TextWindow.WriteLine("")
    TextWindow.WriteLine("Você quer fechar/reiniciar?")
    TextWindow.WriteLine("")
    resposta = TextWindow.Read()
    If resposta = "fechar" Then
        Program.End()
    ElseIf resposta <> "reiniciar" Then
        continua = 0
    EndIf
EndWhile
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/SmallBasic.sb).

Comment: Ah, muito obrigado pela resposta, bigown! Eu tinha ideia que seria melhor usar um laço `While`, mas não tinha ideia como implementá-lo e por causa disso eu usei `Goto`. E também pensei que `Program.GetArgument(20)` era o que eu queria, mas fui provado errado :)

Comment: Mas, se eu quero que o programa fecha-se e reabre-se rapidamente se eu digitar "reiniciar", com o programa voltando como aberto pela primeira vez, qual seria os passos para chegar até esse método de reinício?

Comment: Desconheço uma forma de fazer isto e nem sei se faz sentido fazê-lo.

Comment: Só para ter um design bonito, para a tela do console não fique cheia de frases.

Comment: Limpe a tela então, fechar e começar de novo será pior [`TextWindow.Clear()`](http://smallbasic.com/doc.aspx?o=TextWindow)

Comment: Putz, não tinha ideia! Muito obrigado novamente!